# How can network traffic inside a GKE cluster where Network Policy feature is disabled be controlled without recreating all node pools?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running GKE cluster version 1.20 in which Dataplane V2 and the Network Policy features are disabled.

Per the GKE documentation, enabling the Network Policy feature on non-Dataplane V2 clusters [requires recreating all node pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#overhead_limitations_and_caveats).

My cluster have two node pools for various workloads and I want to make sure pod A can communicate only with pod B, both on the same node pool, without recreating the other node pool.

I also want to avoid achieving this using OS-based solutions such as Linux `iptables` or GCP-based solutions such as VPC firewall rules. It must be an in-cluster solution.

Comment: Do you just not want to recreate node pools or is there something preventing you from doing so?

Comment: Currently something is preventing me from doing so and therefore I wanted to look into other options but it looks like there is no clean workaround for this.

Comment: Yeah - there's not really a good way to do this w/o creating new node pools.  Depending on how much you have deployed, you may want to create a new cluster with Dataplane v2 enabled and migrate your workloads, but if not then creating new node pools with network policy enforcement enabled is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Dataplane V2 has Network Policies enabled by default, you don't have to enable them

Per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/dataplane-v2)

> Warning: GKE Dataplane V2 comes with Kubernetes network policy
> enforcement built-in. This means that you don't need to enable network
> policy in clusters that use GKE Dataplane V2. If you try to explicitly
> enable or disable network policy enforcement in a cluster that uses
> GKE Dataplane V2, the request will fail with the error message
> Enabling NetworkPolicy for clusters with
> DatapathProvider=ADVANCED_DATAPATH is not allowed..

Comment: In the first paragraph of my question I stated that Dataplane V2 is disabled on my cluster.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I miss-read your initial question. In that case, I'm afraid there is no way to enable network policies without re-creating the nodes. However, keep in mind that the nodes are re-created one at a time. So in theory that should distribute your workloads, as one node will be taken down, Kubernetes will reschedule it on a different node and so until all nodes have Network Policies enabled. There is a recommendation in the same doc you linked above to temporarily increase your cluster size to make sure there is enough capacity to run your workloads.

Comment: Yes, but still, I must find a way to enforce network policies without recreating nodes. I'm currently looking into installing other CNI plugins, such as Weave Net. I was able to install it and create a network policy with the desired configuration but for some reason traffic is still allowed between pods.

Comment: Yeah that would not work i'm afraid, GKE already has a CNI deployed which is the Google one, you cannot deploy two CNI's in the same Kubernetes cluster, beside the control plane has to be configured to use whatever CNI you want to use, and in GKE you don't have access to the control plane.
I'm afraid enabling network policies is the only way